This app has 1 unprocessed crash. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them
I am using flavors (dev, prod, profile) in my Flutter application. Now, I want to use Firebase crashlytics in my app. Crashlytics dashboard shows "This app has 1 unprocessed crash. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them". I have the upload dSYM script as follows: 
and FIREBASE_PLIST is user defined as: 
upload dSYM is run at last in Build phase. However I am unable to run my project now. It throws an error: Failed to build iOS app Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
Can anyone help me in fixing this issue. I am using flavors, there's not much available about uploading dYSM with flavors setup

If you're obfuscating your code while building, Firebase requires you to upload the generated dSYM files for crash reporting. To do this, follow these steps:
Use the following command to build the app:
flutter build ipa --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./app/debuginfo/dev/v138_58_ios --release

This command builds the app with obfuscation enabled and outputs the dSYM files to the app/debuginfo/dev/v138_58_ios directory within your project.
Locate the dSYM files in the specified directory, compress them into a .zip file, and upload this zip file to Firebase. This step is essential to enable Firebase Crashlytics to accurately decode and display stack traces.
This is what Firebase means by "uploading dSYM files."
see this new method

I am using xcode to build my ios app or archive it. I am not obfuscating it as far as i know. How to create a build script for dSYM upload in build phase? So that I don't need to upload everytime there's a crash. How to do it with flavors? The script I mean
